# Событие touch не срабатывают если страница прокручивается на Iphone safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, touch-event

Если страница прокручивается (с ускорением) то touch события не срабатывают **на белом прямоугольнике**

Демо codepen
https://codepen.io/-greg-/full/MWyjJNK

```js
const fix = document.querySelector('.fix')
const text = document.querySelector('.handle')

fix.addEventListener('touchstart', handle) //nothing happens while the page is scrolling
fix.addEventListener('touchend', handle) //nothing happens while the page is scrolling
fix.addEventListener('mousedown', handle) //nothing happens while the page is scrolling
fix.addEventListener('touchmove', handle) //nothing happens while the page is scrolling

function handle(e) {
  text.innerText = e.type
  console.log(e)
}
```

```css
.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000vh;
  background: rgb(226, 252, 193);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(226, 252, 193, 1) 0%, rgba(182, 251, 176, 1) 3%, rgba(204, 128, 151, 1) 49%, rgba(134, 133, 189, 1) 75%, rgba(71, 153, 222, 1) 98%, rgba(0, 204, 247, 1) 100%);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fix {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.handle {
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Old versions of Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll"></section>
<div class="fix">
  <p class="handle"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Перевел, спасибо.

Comment: Не совсем понял, какая логика вам требуется в конечном итоге. Может быть, вам при скроллинге страницы все же нужно отлавливать события всей страницы или конкретно скролящийся секции? В данном случае, получается, обработчики должны подключаться только в том случае, если при создании ускоренного скроллинга случайно задеть этот самый фиксированный блок (и то должны только в том случае, если с этим не связаны какие-нибудь подводные камни и детали реализации всплытия в мобилке в условиях скрола).

Comment: Идея такая - есть фиксированный блок (белая плашка) на нем можно производить какие то действия (click, touchstart, touchmove), НО если в сафари прокручивать страницу (свайп с ускорением) то, пока она скроллится ни одно событие в fix панели не работает. В андроиде пока страница прокручивается можно на белой плашке кликать, touch... и все события работают) Проверял на 4 версиях iphone с разными версиями safari

Comment: Понял. В принципе, если это действительно просто сафаривская фича, то ее можно назвать вполне удобной. Чтобы, пока скролишь, не задеть или не запустить что-нибудь, почему бы не ограничить эти события. Вашей плашке вообще обязательно работать прямо во время скроллинга? Или конкретно на этом завязаны ещё какие-то идеи?

Comment: Белая плашка - свайп меню, если хоть немного при таче запустить скроллинг страницы (у меня так же не срабатывает stoppropagation для белой плашки) то вызвать свайпменю событием touchmove невозможно так как страница прокрутилось и событие тач на белой плашке сафари заблокировал.
Вот и получается что ногтиком нужно аккуратненько свайпать меню. Я уменьшил демку до самой проблемы (конфликт событий)

Comment: Я на codepan обновил демку, одно из моих предположений - глюк из-за очередной "фичи" сафари [GestureEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GestureEvent) которая не поддерживается ни одним браузером  и не является стандартом. Еще была идея заблокировать click, touchstart, touchmove, touchend на белой плашке через `stoppropagation` но [на сколько я понимаю](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling) window самый высокий в уровне event propagation и по этому если скроллить белый прямоугольник то скроллится и вся страница